# Client App for a RESTfull API - Richardson Maturity Model - The right way

Tags: rest, api

**The Context,**

I'm working on a RESTfull API using Symfony2 (My API implementation is mainly based on [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) and  [Serializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle), I also introduced [Hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) in order to reach [the third Level](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3) of
 [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) (as [Level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1) and [2](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level2) are fully respected).

**My Question,**

My problem is related to my "Symfony2" Client application, I'm using [Guzzle library](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) to request my API but I'm struggling with the way I should manage relationships between resources.

**Let's make it clearer, here's a relevant example,**

Lets say I've a `resource A` that's related to a `resource B`, The main client side feature I'm working on is creating a new resource A, but creating A also means creating a related `B resource`.
The client app should target an API method that have the following signature/route : `<POST> /api/resourceA` .

But as creating `A` requires creating `B` and related it to `A`, I should then taget the "`<POST> /api/resourceB`" service then getting my `201` response with a linked `B resource`, use that link to call the     relevant `resource B` GET method to get an `Id` (or get it from the `POST` response). add the identifier to the related `ressource A` and then be able to call my `<POST> /api/resourceA` (new) method .

This approach looks too tedious and I was wondering if I'm missing something. I don't want to violate [Level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1) of [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) and I want to easily manage relationship between resources.

Does anyone have an idea on the way I should do that?

**TL;DR**

So to summarize, my constraints are,

- I've one call for one resource
- No call to create A will automatically create B
- The only call that implies relations between resources are instroduced by Hateaous links (on GET and as a part of the PUT/POST responses)

So my current approach (based on those constraints) is,

- POST to create B
- Get B identifier and relate it to A
- POST to create A
- IF creating A fails
- Delete B

A best practice when doing REST is "One action for one resource", So, put another way, my question is:

- Is there a mature bundle/library/tool (around Symfony2) that provides an abstraction Layer that manage relationships between resources provided by a Rest API(s)?
- Any advices or feedback(s) on the way I should manage that are also welcomed.

Comment: Do you use any JS framework like Angular or Emberjs? Because that's one easy way to manage your relationship. When you say "creating A requires creating B", you mean like a 1,n relation between two entities?

Comment: The question is basically a 'recommend a tool' question and violates stackoverflow's rules ... but i think it's an interesting one, so i won't flag it. I haven't come across a **full-featured REST-consumer** library **written in PHP** that i would consider mature in terms of documentation, tests, development activity ... hoping for a surprise :)

Comment: I've run into the same issue recently. I've gone for the approach of creating `ResourceA` with a status field of pending, then creating `ResourceB` than when created triggers a listener to update the status of `ResourceA` to active. Then I've created a command to remove any pending `ResourceA`'s that are over a certain age. I don't think it's the right way but sticking to the same "one action for one resource" methodology has lead me to this thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ALWAYS create A with B (A can't be created without B), then you have kind a complex resource. So the best method is to use `<POST> /api/resourceAB`.

Comment: A should be created with a related B resource only in some specific cases.